# Pytorch - TypeError: ToTensor() takes no arguments using torchvision.transform

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I’m trying to load in a dataset for super-resolution and I have set up two functions which use Compose to crop and resize the images.

The function I have created for the input images works correctly and they are outputting as expected. The transform function for the target images is basically identical, just omitting the resize part of it.

```
def input_trans(c_size, sF):
    return Compose([
        CenterCrop(c_size),
        Resize(c_size // sF),
        ToTensor(),
    ])


def goal_trans(c_size):
    return Compose([
        CenterCrop(c_size),
        ToTensor(),
    ])
```

These functions are used in my dataset class when the images are loaded. I originally had goal = input.Copy() but I have changed it so both input and goal load the image separately. (was testing if the .copy() was the issue

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    input = Image.open(self.image_filenames[idx]).convert('RGB')
    goal = Image.open(self.image_filenames[idx]).convert('RGB')
    if self.input_transform:
        input = self.input_transform(input)
    if self.goal_transform:
        print(goal)
        print(goal.size)
        goal = self.goal_transform(goal)

    return input, goal
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()  # execute this only when run directly, not when imported!
  File "main.py", line 55, in main
    train_model(epoch)
  File "main.py", line 40, in train_model
    for data_item, batch in enumerate(training_data_loader):
  File "C:\Users\[NAME]\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 345, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\[NAME]\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 385, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\[NAME]\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\Users\[NAME]\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "main.py", line 118, in __getitem__
    goal = self.goal_transform(goal)
  File "C:\Users\[NAME]\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 70, in __call__
    img = t(img)
TypeError: ToTensor() takes no arguments
```

Confuses me because it doesn’t seem to have a problem with the first transformation (Ive checked and it does output before crashing).

I would appreciate any help you guys can give,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! nothing to do with torchvision.transforms.

I wasn't actually using the functions above, but inline declarations for compose which I had tried to use previously.

My bad